# records array is missing some values from nested forEach loop

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I'm trying to create a nested for loop to loop through a set of price records and then for every customer ID, I want to copy that price ID from the current customer to the next customer. The code itself works fine from that regard. The issue is that I wanted to use insertMany instead of insert to lower the database roundtrip time. This is when I started encountering some of the issues below.

I’m getting a weird issue that I can’t seem to pinpoint the cause of. Whenever I push to my records array. I only get records with the same customer ID of one of the customers. In the particular example below, I should be getting 3 distinct ids but that isn’t the case. I tried a minimal version of the code and it works fine but with the actual code, it’s not working for some reason. A pinpoint into the right direction is much appreciated!

PS: Do let me know if there is any clarification needed or if my question needs editing as I'm new and want to improve my question quality.

My Current Code

```
    let records= [];
    fromCustomerPricingRecords.forEach((record) => {
        toCustomerIds.forEach((customer) => {
            record.customerId = customer._id;
            delete record._id;
            delete record.createdAt;
            delete record.updatedAt;
            delete record.updatedBy;
            delete record.ownerId;

            record._id = Random.id();
            record.createdAt = new Date();
            record.ownerId = user._id;

            records.push(record);
        });
    });

    CustomerPricings.rawCollection().insertMany(records);
```

Console.log OUTPUT [ should be getting 3 different ids in the finalRecordsArray ]

```
I20220811-11:28:13.969(2)? customerRecords [
I20220811-11:28:13.971(2)?   Document {
I20220811-11:28:13.971(2)?     businessId: '3bLDoazdGqDp42BYW',
I20220811-11:28:13.972(2)?     customerId: '2Nn3J8cAadbPgW6qG',
I20220811-11:28:13.972(2)?     cityId: 'all',
I20220811-11:28:13.972(2)?     applicableStartAt: 2022-08-04T22:00:00.000Z,
I20220811-11:28:13.972(2)?     applicableEndAt: 2022-09-05T22:00:00.000Z,
I20220811-11:28:13.972(2)?     prices: [ [Object] ],
I20220811-11:28:13.973(2)?     _id: 'Hj2iSXnYtE2CdCzXz',
I20220811-11:28:13.973(2)?     createdAt: 2022-08-11T09:28:13.968Z,
I20220811-11:28:13.973(2)?     ownerId: 'SPwHFptZJwTFvZfMG'
I20220811-11:28:13.973(2)?   }
I20220811-11:28:13.973(2)? ]
I20220811-11:28:13.974(2)? toCustomerIds [
I20220811-11:28:13.975(2)?   {
I20220811-11:28:13.975(2)?     _id: 'v6c8XjytnbdFoPqgz',
I20220811-11:28:13.975(2)?     name: 'Test_CRC',
I20220811-11:28:13.975(2)?     phoneNumber: '+201551411376',
I20220811-11:28:13.975(2)?     email: 'amr.shawki44+crc@gmail.com',
I20220811-11:28:13.976(2)?     address: 'CRC@CRC_ROAD',
I20220811-11:28:13.976(2)?     isPrimaryMaster: true,
I20220811-11:28:13.976(2)?     active: true,
I20220811-11:28:13.976(2)?     customerGroupId: '4KoaSYfGz6WPR7CBJ',
I20220811-11:28:13.976(2)?     nSt: 'accepted',
I20220811-11:28:13.976(2)?     nid: 'ze2FCvGqDCfTG8u9X'
I20220811-11:28:13.977(2)?   },
I20220811-11:28:13.977(2)?   {
I20220811-11:28:13.977(2)?     _id: 'RPXoQb4hzARjECZXf',
I20220811-11:28:13.977(2)?     name: 'Test_Business_3',
I20220811-11:28:13.977(2)?     active: true,
I20220811-11:28:13.977(2)?     customerGroupId: '4KoaSYfGz6WPR7CBJ'
I20220811-11:28:13.977(2)?   },
I20220811-11:28:13.978(2)?   {
I20220811-11:28:13.978(2)?     _id: '2Nn3J8cAadbPgW6qG',
I20220811-11:28:13.978(2)?     name: 'Test_Business_1',
I20220811-11:28:13.978(2)?     customerGroupId: '4KoaSYfGz6WPR7CBJ',
I20220811-11:28:13.978(2)?     active: true
I20220811-11:28:13.978(2)?   }
I20220811-11:28:13.979(2)? ]
I20220811-11:28:13.979(2)? finalRecordsArray [
I20220811-11:28:13.979(2)?   Document {
I20220811-11:28:13.979(2)?     businessId: '3bLDoazdGqDp42BYW',
I20220811-11:28:13.979(2)?     customerId: '2Nn3J8cAadbPgW6qG',
I20220811-11:28:13.979(2)?     cityId: 'all',
I20220811-11:28:13.980(2)?     applicableStartAt: 2022-08-04T22:00:00.000Z,
I20220811-11:28:13.980(2)?     applicableEndAt: 2022-09-05T22:00:00.000Z,
I20220811-11:28:13.980(2)?     prices: [ [Object] ],
I20220811-11:28:13.980(2)?     _id: 'Hj2iSXnYtE2CdCzXz',
I20220811-11:28:13.980(2)?     createdAt: 2022-08-11T09:28:13.968Z,
I20220811-11:28:13.980(2)?     ownerId: 'SPwHFptZJwTFvZfMG'
I20220811-11:28:13.981(2)?   },
I20220811-11:28:13.981(2)?   Document {
I20220811-11:28:13.981(2)?     businessId: '3bLDoazdGqDp42BYW',
I20220811-11:28:13.981(2)?     customerId: '2Nn3J8cAadbPgW6qG',
I20220811-11:28:13.981(2)?     cityId: 'all',
I20220811-11:28:13.981(2)?     applicableStartAt: 2022-08-04T22:00:00.000Z,
I20220811-11:28:13.982(2)?     applicableEndAt: 2022-09-05T22:00:00.000Z,
I20220811-11:28:13.982(2)?     prices: [ [Object] ],
I20220811-11:28:13.982(2)?     _id: 'Hj2iSXnYtE2CdCzXz',
I20220811-11:28:13.982(2)?     createdAt: 2022-08-11T09:28:13.968Z,
I20220811-11:28:13.982(2)?     ownerId: 'SPwHFptZJwTFvZfMG'
I20220811-11:28:13.982(2)?   },
I20220811-11:28:13.983(2)?   Document {
I20220811-11:28:13.983(2)?     businessId: '3bLDoazdGqDp42BYW',
I20220811-11:28:13.983(2)?     customerId: '2Nn3J8cAadbPgW6qG',
I20220811-11:28:13.983(2)?     cityId: 'all',
I20220811-11:28:13.983(2)?     applicableStartAt: 2022-08-04T22:00:00.000Z,
I20220811-11:28:13.983(2)?     applicableEndAt: 2022-09-05T22:00:00.000Z,
I20220811-11:28:13.984(2)?     prices: [ [Object] ],
I20220811-11:28:13.984(2)?     _id: 'Hj2iSXnYtE2CdCzXz',
I20220811-11:28:13.984(2)?     createdAt: 2022-08-11T09:28:13.968Z,
I20220811-11:28:13.984(2)?     ownerId: 'SPwHFptZJwTFvZfMG'
I20220811-11:28:13.984(2)?   }
I20220811-11:28:13.984(2)? ]
```

Small example that works

```
const fromCustomerPricingRecords= [1];
const toCustomerIds= [1,2,3]
let records= [];
fromCustomerPricingRecords.forEach((record) => {
    toCustomerIds.forEach((customer) => {
        record= customer
        records.push(record)
    });
});
console.log(records)

// OUTPUT
// [ 1, 2, 3 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that your final array records[] contains the same object in each index. Inside the inner loop you add a new element via push() but also mutate prev elements (use the same record object).

Comment: this is small example which is closer to your issue: 

`const fromCustomerPricingRecords= [{id:1, customer_id:1}];
const toCustomerIds= [1,2,3]
let records= [];
fromCustomerPricingRecords.forEach((record) => {
    toCustomerIds.forEach((customer) => {
        record.customer_id = customer
        records.push(record)
    });
});
console.log(records)
// [{id: 1, customer_id: 3},{id: 1, customer_id: 3},{id: 1, customer_id: 3}]`

try write inside inner loop: let newRecord = {...record} and already modify newRecord object and push it

Answer (score 0):

Point in the right direction -

1. Notice `Hj2iSXnYtE2CdCzXz` appears 4 times in your console.log output. Once in customerRecords[0]._id and once in each of the finalRecordsArray